# How to store table Field(column) name into An Array?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is the my code and I am trying to store the value into the Array.

```
$result = $cid->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM commissions");
echo $count = $result->num_rows;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo $row['Field'];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

I am trying to do this `$ar[]=$row;` but there is nothing display !!

```
$result = $cid->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM commissions");
echo $count = $result->num_rows;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    ar[] = $row;
    echo "<br/>";
}
for($i = 0, $i<12, $i++) {
    echo ar['field'][0];
}
```

Nothing Display in the output

Comment: Where is that `$ar[]=$row;` part?

Comment: Maybe you can clarify things by telling us your desired output?

Comment: unixarmy i have Edit check it !!

Answer (score 2):

You can do following way to store column name into array. Read comment after every line

**For PDO**

```
$rs = $cid->query('SELECT * FROM commissions');// your query
for ($i = 0; $i < $rs->field_count(); $i++) {/// count nu of column
    $col = $rs->fetch_fields()($i);//Returns metadata for a column in a result set
    $columns[] = $col['name'];// get name from metedata
}
print_r($columns);
```

**For mysqli**

```
$rs = $cid->query('SELECT * FROM commissions');// your query

        $col = $rs->fetch_fields();//Returns metadata for a column in a result set
           foreach ($col as $val) {
           $columns[]=$val->name;
    }
    print_r($columns);
```

Comment: First you have to check the code and give the answer ??

Comment: Its working for me. Have you got any error or problem while using my code??

Comment: columnCount() definition ??

Comment: there is Error  Call to undefined method mysqli_result::columnCount()

Comment: ohh its on pdo and you use mysqli thats the problem.

Comment: then what should i do ?